# node-mlt - setting argument for watermark

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, melt

I have get project where server get json file and media file and convert to xml. Server use mlt with node-mlt lib. My task is add watermark. I did it, but I can't find any description for node-mlt method arguments except URL to file. node-mlt have example:

```
var watermark = new MLT.Filter.Watermark({resource:'/home/jeffrey/Desktop/signature.jpg'});
```

Does anybody know how I must setting opacity, size, position for this method? Standard arguments for mlt this lib don't recognize.